# Check if date has past other date don't work in certain situations

Tags: php

I have done research on how to figure out how I can use a if else statement to determine if a certain date has past another date or not but I notice this script works how it should work but if the day is a certain number for example 2 in the $present_time variable then it gives out the right output which is the else statement

This works

**INPUT**

```
<?php

$time_format = 'n-j-Y g:i A';
$time_zone = 'America/phoenix';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($time_format, '9-2-2021 11:28 AM', new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
$present_time = $date->format($time_format);

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($time_format, '9-21-2021 9:57 PM', new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
$end_time = $date->format($time_format);

if($present_time > $end_time) {
    
   echo 'Present time has pass the end time.';

} 

else{
    
     echo 'Present time has not pass the end time.';

}

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

*Present time has not pass the end time.*

but if I change the $present_time variables day to a 3 then I get an unexpected output which is the if statement and I should not get the else statement to show because the $end_time obviously has a later date.

**INPUT**

```
<?php

$time_format = 'n-j-Y g:i A';
$time_zone = 'America/phoenix';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($time_format, '9-3-2021 11:28 AM', new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
$present_time = $date->format($time_format);

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($time_format, '9-21-2021 9:57 PM', new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
$end_time = $date->format($time_format);

if($present_time > $end_time) {
    
   echo 'Present time has pass the end time.';

} 

else{
    
    echo 'Present time has not pass the end time.';

}

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

*Present time has pass the end time.*

So how can I get this to work properly to show the correct condition properly in these situations.

I got this method based on this tutorial

https://write.corbpie.com/php-check-if-current-date-time-has-passed-a-set-date-time/

but I need to use the hyphen character so that is why it looks a little different from that  tutorial.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. It seems like it's a `string` comparation instead of `date` comparation, **2 < 21** and **3 > 21**.

Comment: I fixed my wording right now. I put set time rather than end time so you think that is the problem then? I still don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: So you want to compare the time portions of a date time and ignore the date? Or do you simply want to check if a given date time is before/after another date time?

Comment: I think you converted your time objects into regular strings.  Comparing the string representations of time is not the same as comparing time objects.

Comment: @waterloomatt thanks for responding well I just want to compare both variables AKA the $present_time variable and the $end_time variable  which they both include their own date and time in each variable so I don't want to just compare a single digit in each variables I just want to compare the whole thing that is in the $present_time and $end_time which include the date and time in each of them I notice a bug when the day  is a certain number I want to find a way where I can get rid of this bug.

Comment: @waterloomatt Thanks for the correction. `Time()` does not take any parameters indeed. It returns current timestamp.

Comment: No prob. I think I know where you were going with that though. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are *formatting* your dates and then comparing the *strings* when you should be comparing the DateTime objects themselves.

When you compare the strings "9-3-..." to "9-21-...", the first one will be bigger because it compares the string character by character.

- position 1 `9` & `9` are equal
- position 2 `-` & `-` are equal
- position 3 `3` & `2` are not equal.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1cdce859a8a5c59b92118afdbea581cc254ca00

```
<?php

$time_format = 'n-j-Y g:i A';
$time_zone = 'America/phoenix';

$first = DateTime::createFromFormat($time_format, '9-3-2021 11:28 AM', new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
// $present_time = $first->format($time_format);
// Once formatted, these are strings. Don't compare these.
// string(17) "9-3-2021 11:28 AM"

$second = DateTime::createFromFormat($time_format, '9-21-2021 9:57 PM', new DateTimeZone($time_zone));
// $end_time = $second->format($time_format);
// Once formatted, these are strings. Don't compare these.
// string(17) "9-21-2021 9:57 PM"


if($first > $second) {
   echo 'Present time has pass the end time.';
} else {
    echo 'Present time has not pass the end time.';
}
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much @waterloomatt I did not realize that till you explained it. It now works how it should now.